# Is there a point to setting __all__ and then using leading underscores anyway?

Tags: python, cpython

I've been reading through the source for the cpython HTTP package for fun and profit, and noticed that in server.py they have the `__all__` variable set but also use a leading underscore for the function `_quote_html(html)`.

Isn't this redundant? Don't both serve to limit what's imported by `from HTTP import *`?

Why do they do both?

Comment: Given that shouldn't use `import *` at all, `__all__` is mostly useless, and the only way to really mark things as internal is to prefix them with underscores.

Comment: Would you mark the question as resolved? Just for the great justice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from the *"private-by-convention"* functions with `_leading_underscores`, there are:

- Quite a few `import`ed names;
- Four class names;
- Three function names *without* leading underscores;
- Two string *"constants"*; and
- One local variable (`nobody`).

If `__all__` wasn't defined to cover only the classes, all of these would also be added to your namespace by a wildcard `from server import *`.

Yes, you could just use one method or the other, but I think the leading underscore is a stronger sign than the exclusion from `__all__`; the latter says *"you probably won't need this often"*, the former says *"keep out unless you know what you're doing"*. They both have their place.

Answer (score 5):

`__all__` indeed serves as a limit when doing `from HTTP import *`; prefixing `_` to the name of a function or method is a convention for informing the user that that item should be considered private and thus used at his/her own risk.

Answer (score 3):

This is mostly a documentation thing, in a similar vein to comments. A leading underscore is a clearer indication to a person *reading the code* that particular functions or variables aren't part of the public API than having that person check each name against `__all__`. [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#public-and-internal-interfaces) explicitly recommends using both conventions in this way:

> To better support introspection, modules should explicitly declare
>   the names in their public API using the `__all__` attribute. Setting
>   `__all__` to an empty list indicates that the module has no public API.
>
> Even with `__all__` set appropriately, internal interfaces (packages,
>   modules, classes, functions, attributes or other names) should still
>   be prefixed with a single leading underscore.